# import clusters in python

Tags: python, python-3.6, importerror

I am facing error during import clusters in python 3.6.

```
import clusters
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-63e76c87813b> in <module>
----> 1 import clusters

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clusters'
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You just want `cluster`, drop the s:

```
import cluster
```

..should work. Here's the [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/cluster/) for reference